# Hot to avoid Python Dask Logistic regression Multiple constant columns detected error

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, logistic-regression, dask

I am using python3 with Dask for fitting a logistic regression model.
I have two numpy arrays x, y 
And I use this code to convert them into dask arrays

```
data = da.from_array(data, chunks=(1000, data.shape[1]))
labels = da.from_array(labels)
```

and then

```
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
l = LogisticRegression()
l.fit(data, labels)
```

To fit the logistic regression but keep getting this error

> raise ValueError('Multiple constant columns detected!') ValueError:
>   Multiple constant columns detected!

Found [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-glm/blob/master/dask_glm/utils.py) that this is related to dask df's but I am training on an array. Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do some preprocessing to your `data`. Since feature columns with constant values don't provide too much help in making prediction/estimation in lots of ML tasks and those are places where `std == 0`, we can get rid of them at the beginning by doing the following:

```
data = data[:, ~np.all(data==data[0,:], axis=0)]
```

Comment: Those features are transfer learning features from a deep learning model, it's possible that some of them have zero variance, and should not prevent us from creating a logistic regression model, it works in SKlearn and make sense.

Comment: Yea, I was wondering why dask has that line of code to check if there are more than 1 feature that have std == 0. My guess is that it tries to reduce the space?

Comment: reducing the space is nice, but should not break the run, seems like a bug?

Comment: I agree! Has anyone raised an issue in the repo?

Comment: I have not yet come across the issue. Any updates on this matter?